# Java Apache POI Generating Receipt Table in Word

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I need to make a java application that takes basic Form Entries, generate a receipt with those entries in the form of a Header (Receipt Number), Subheaders(Name, Address, etc) and the table with said entries in a Word file.

Now I have figured out the headers part but I can't seem to find any documentation on Apache POI on how to manipulate tables. Any idea on how I can create n rows with m columns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apache poi add table in word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034590/apache-poi-add-table-in-word-document)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

See this [POI word tables tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_tables.htm)

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableRow;

public class CreateTable {

   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

      //Blank Document
      XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        
      //Write the Document in file system
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("create_table.docx"));
        
      //create table
      XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
        
      //create first row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
      tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
      tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two, row one");
      tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three, row one");
        
      //create second row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();
      tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
      tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
      tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");
        
      //create third row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow();
      tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
      tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
      tableRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");
    
      document.write(out);
      out.close();
      System.out.println("create_table.docx written successully");
   }
}
```

Which creates

[image]